# Call setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible Method in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to show Network Activity Indicator in my iOS app status bar.
How can I call static `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` method in react native dynamically?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a reference inside the StatusBar component, and you'll have access to it's static methods.Just call `this.statusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(boolean)` in the parent component.

```
  <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="blue"
     barStyle="light-content"
     ref={(statusBar) => this.statusBar = statusBar}
   />
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to mount it. You can use

`StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(true)`